# Using Python and Beautiful Soup how can I capture an empty tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to read web data into a list.  The problem is that there are empty points in the data that I need to account for.

For example, for the data below I want my final output to be a list like:

Plano, TX
New York, NY
Denver, CO
NA
Chicago, IL
San Francisco, CA

```
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Plano, TX</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">New York, NY</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Denver, CO</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality"></span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Chicago, IL</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">San Francisco, CA</span>
```

Currently I'm trying to print out the results to verify them before I append them to a list, my code looks like:

```
for span in div.find('span', {'itemprop':'addressLocality'}):
    if span:
        print(span)
    else:
        print('NA')
```

This code gives me the following output which does not account for the empty tag:

Plano, TX
New York, NY
Denver, CO
Chicago, IL
San Francisco, CA

I've just started learning Python and Beautiful Soup.
I've tried variations of if..else; try: ... except: ; and .contents.   I'm sure it's something simple.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `find_all`, and if there's no text, fill it with "N/A"

```
spans = div.find_all('span', {'itemprop':'addressLocality'})
cities = [span.get_text() if span.get_text() else "N/A" for span in spans]
print cities
```

If you want to stick with your original code structure, you're very close, but try this instead:

```
for span in div.find_all('span', {'itemprop':'addressLocality'}):
    if span.get_text():
        print(span.get_text())
    else:
        print('NA')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `find_all`, which returns all instances of a tag found. `find` returns just the first one found.

`if span:` will evaluate to `True`. You want to get the text contained using `get_text` and check if it is non-empty.

Try this:

```
cities = []

for span in div.findAll('span', {'itemprop': 'addressLocality'}):
    text = span.get_text()
    if len(span) > 0:
        cities.append(text)

print(cities)
```